# PyArmorで起きるエラー「 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 6114: illegal multibyte sequence」

Tags: python

main.pyというPythonファイルを難読化するために、以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
pyarmor obfuscate main.py
```

すると、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
ERROR    'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 6114: illegal multibyte sequence
```

上記のエラーメッセージでGoogle検索かけると、似たような事例は出てくるのですが、PyArmorでの対処法が分かりません。

どうしたらエラーを出さずにPyArmorを実行できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これでは無いですか？ 対象スクリプト(この場合は`main.py`)の最初の行に、そのファイルのエンコーディングタイプを追記しておけば良いのではないでしょうか。

['XXX' codec can't decode byte 0xXX](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/questions.html#xxx-codec-can-t-decode-byte-0xxx)

> Add the exact source encode at the begin of the script. For example:
>   スクリプトの最初に正確なソースエンコードを追加します。 例えば：
>
> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> ```
>
> Refer to https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding

Comment: この方法で出来ました